# Best Practice for variable with SQL in cfquery

Tags: sql, coldfusion

If I had a variable with with SQL code such as `#PreserveSingleQuotes(arguments.sql)#`

1. What is the best way to run this code?
2. Is there a way to run this if SQL injection attacks are possible?

This question is a follow up to [Variable as SQL in cfquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627795/variable-as-sql-in-cfquery)

Comment: Regarding question 2, it is a good practice to validate user input before the cfquery tag gets to see it.

Comment: Agreed. By the time it comes to storing something, one should be certain it's actually someone one wants to store. Parametrising an SQL statement should be a fall back, not the front line. Parametrising's main focus should be to improve DB performance, with SQL-injection-prevention a happy side effect.

Comment: Agreed about bind variables. With regards to `PreserveSingleQuotes`, I do not think there is any reasonable way to protect queries once you use it. You are basically reverting to pre-MX behavior when CF did *not* protect queries by auto-escaping  single quotes. So you are working without a net. Unless you are absolutely certain the sql *and* parameters you are executing are safe, it should be avoided.

Comment: This question and answer covers some of the same stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687562/coldfusion-executing-dynamic-query-containing-cfqueryparam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#1 is a bit of funny question, because you don't have a great number of options to hand. From a ColdFusion perspective you can either run it via `<cfquery>` or via `Query.cfc`. Alternatively DB systems will be able to take a string containing SQL and execute it, but that really just abstracts the issue slightly from CF to the DB. I'm not sure there are other options.

As far as #2 goes, this is a big problem when using `<cfquery>` as there's no good (or at least sensible) way of mitigating SQL injection (and certainly no way of optimising the SQL's compilation process), because the only way to parametrise the values in the statement is via `<cfqueryparam>`, and one cannot embed those in your string full of SQL. The solution here is to use `Query.cfc` (I don't believe I am recommending using `Query.cfc` because it's about the most poorly implemented part of the CFML language, IMO), because one can specify either positional or named parameters within the SQL string, and pass the parameter values separately.

In closing, you should always definitely pass values as parameters rather than hand-coding them in the SQL statement, and if that means not using a pre-created string for the SQL statement, then so be it.